# Graphql Query Objects in Laravel

Tags: php, graphql, laravel-5.5, graphql-php

So I have the basics narrowed down using GraphQL. In my laravel APP

My graphql returns the ID, tenant_reference and roles but i cant seem to add in custom attributes its an object with custom keys it just return null or if i try to add in a key it errors out.

Heres an example of the JSON representation of the data:

```
"data": {
    "vendor_id": "b8faaf26-c8a6-3560-8357-f789f3325b0c",
    "roles": [
        "manager"
    ],
    "tenant_reference": "lightcoral70",
    "custom_attributes": {
        "fred": "test",
        "one": "test2"
    }
}
```

Heres the type snippet:

```
public function fields() {
    return [
        'id' => [
            'type' => GraphQlType::nonNull(GraphQlType::string()),
            'description' => 'The id of the user',
            'alias' => 'user_id', // Use 'alias', if the database column is different from the type name
        ],
        'tenant_reference' => [
            'type' => GraphQlType::nonNull(GraphQlType::string()),
            'description' => 'Tenant reference this user belongs to',
            'alias' => 'tenant'
        ],
        'roles' => [
            'type' => GraphQlType::listOf(GraphQlType::string()),
            'description' => 'User roles'
        ],
        'custom_attributes' => [
            'type' => GraphQlType::listOf(GraphQlType::string()),
        ]
    ];
}
```

Heres the query snippet:

```
protected $repository;

protected $attributes = [
    'name' => 'Users query'
];

public function __construct(UserRepository $repository) {
    $this->repository = $repository;
}

/**
 * @return \GraphQL\Type\Definition\ListOfType|null
 */
public function type() {
    return GraphQlType::listOf(GraphQL::type('user_record'));
}

/**
 * Arguments we can use to filter the query
 * @return array
 */
public function args() {

    return [
        'sub' => [
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => GraphQlType::string()
        ],
        'tenantReference' => [
            'name' => 'tenantReference',
            'type' => GraphQlType::string()
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 */
public function resolve($root, $args) {
    return User::where([
        "tenant_reference" => $args['tenantReference'],
        "sub" => $args['id']
    ])->get();
}
```

This is essentially what I want to achieve using the graphiql emulator:

Bare in mind that the custom attributes can be anything. Eg. i could add another key dynamically twitter: urlhere

```
{
    user_record(
        id:"b8faaf26-c8a6-3560-8357-f789f3325b0c",
        tenantReference:"lightcoral70"
    ) 
    {
       id,
       tenant_reference,
       roles,
       custom_attributes
          fred
    }
}
```

This is what it reutrn using the graphiql

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this query on graphql

```
{
user_record(
    id:"b8faaf26-c8a6-3560-8357-f789f3325b0c",
    tenantReference:"lightcoral70"
) 
{
   id,
   tenant_reference,
   roles,
   custom_attributes{
      fred
    }
}
```

}